# When clicking on a Google Play URL from a PhoneGap application (on Android), how do we bring users directly there with no prompt menu dialogs?

Tags: android, url, google-play

Currently when we click on that link, it will give us a prompt menu dialog asking whether to Open in Browser, Bookmark, etc.

How do we make it go direct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `market://` protocol instead of `http://`? That gets opened directly by the Play Store instead of the browser. The format of the url is `market://details?id=your.app.id`, obviously replacing `your.app.id` with your app ID.